# List of all characters that String.Trim() removes?

Tags: c#, .net

Obviously primary usage of Trim is to remove leading and ending whitespace from string like:

```
"  hello  ".Trim(); // results in "hello"
```

But Trim also removes extra characters like `\n`, `\r` and `\t`, so:

```
"  \nhello\r\t  ".Trim(); // it also produces "hello"
```

Is there a definite list of all characters (preferably in string escaped format, like `\n`) that `Trim` will remove?

**EDIT**: Thanks for detailed answers - I now know EXACT chars. This [Wikipedia list that @RayKoopa left in comments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) is probably best looking format for me.

Comment: From MSDN: `The Trim() method removes any leading and trailing characters that produce a return value of true when they are passed to the Char.IsWhiteSpace method.`

Comment: Which would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character AFAIK

Comment: So you can get a list here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: There is also `Trim(char[])` method that allows you to specify the characters to trim if you don't like the default set.

Comment: why just you filter the string with regex     return Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+", "", RegexOptions.Compiled); and then trim it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can take a look at the source code for the `String` class [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,6cd0b6bfa580e501)

The public `Trim()` method calls an internal helper method named `TrimHelper()`:

```
 public String Trim() {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        return TrimHelper(TrimBoth);        
 }
```

`TrimHelper()` looks like this:

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
        private String TrimHelper(int trimType) {
            //end will point to the first non-trimmed character on the right
            //start will point to the first non-trimmed character on the Left
            int end = this.Length-1;
            int start=0;

            //Trim specified characters.
            if (trimType !=TrimTail)  {
                for (start=0; start < this.Length; start++) {
                    if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(this[start]) && !IsBOMWhitespace(this[start])) break;
                }
            }

            if (trimType !=TrimHead) {
                for (end= Length -1; end >= start;  end--) {
                    if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(this[end])  && !IsBOMWhitespace(this[start])) break;
                }
            }

            return CreateTrimmedString(start, end);
        }
```

So the bulk of your question basically lies in the check for `Char.IsWhiteSpace` method,

[`char.cs`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs,3b2919f97584ef55)

```
   [Pure]
    public static bool IsWhiteSpace(char c) {

        if (IsLatin1(c)) {
            return (IsWhiteSpaceLatin1(c));
        }
        return CharUnicodeInfo.IsWhiteSpace(c);
    }
```

If it's a Latin character, then this is what constitutes white space:

```
 private static bool IsWhiteSpaceLatin1(char c) {

            // There are characters which belong to UnicodeCategory.Control but are considered as white spaces.
            // We use code point comparisons for these characters here as a temporary fix.

            // U+0009 = <control> HORIZONTAL TAB
            // U+000a = <control> LINE FEED
            // U+000b = <control> VERTICAL TAB
            // U+000c = <contorl> FORM FEED
            // U+000d = <control> CARRIAGE RETURN
            // U+0085 = <control> NEXT LINE
            // U+00a0 = NO-BREAK SPACE
            if ((c == ' ') || (c >= '\x0009' && c <= '\x000d') || c == '\x00a0' || c == '\x0085') {
                return (true);
            }
            return (false);
        }
```

Otherwise we have to go to [`CharUnicodeInfo.cs`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/charunicodeinfo.cs,a0868a2c77f22d0c), which uses an Enum to check the whitespace character

```
   internal static bool IsWhiteSpace(char c)
        {
            UnicodeCategory uc = GetUnicodeCategory(c);
            // In Unicode 3.0, U+2028 is the only character which is under the category "LineSeparator".
            // And U+2029 is th eonly character which is under the category "ParagraphSeparator".
            switch (uc) {
                case (UnicodeCategory.SpaceSeparator):
                case (UnicodeCategory.LineSeparator):
                case (UnicodeCategory.ParagraphSeparator):
                    return (true);
            }

            return (false);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

`Trim` (without parameters) removes characters for which [`IsWhiteSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `true`:

> White space characters are the following Unicode characters:
>
> - Members of the SpaceSeparator category, which includes the characters SPACE (U+0020), NO-BREAK SPACE (U+00A0), OGHAM SPACE MARK (U+1680), EN QUAD (U+2000), EM QUAD (U+2001), EN SPACE (U+2002), EM SPACE (U+2003), THREE-PER-EM SPACE (U+2004), FOUR-PER-EM SPACE (U+2005), SIX-PER-EM SPACE (U+2006), FIGURE SPACE (U+2007), PUNCTUATION SPACE (U+2008), THIN SPACE (U+2009), HAIR SPACE (U+200A), NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE (U+202F), MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE (U+205F), and IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE (U+3000).
> - Members of the LineSeparator category, which consists solely of the LINE SEPARATOR character (U+2028).
> - Members of the ParagraphSeparator category, which consists solely of the PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR character (U+2029).
> - The characters CHARACTER TABULATION (U+0009), LINE FEED (U+000A), LINE TABULATION (U+000B), FORM FEED (U+000C), CARRIAGE RETURN (U+000D), and NEXT LINE (U+0085).

According to http://referencesource.microsoft.com:

```
public static bool IsWhiteSpace(char c) { // char.IsWhiteSpace
          
    if (IsLatin1(c)) {
        return (IsWhiteSpaceLatin1(c));
    }
    return CharUnicodeInfo.IsWhiteSpace(c);
}

private static bool IsWhiteSpaceLatin1(char c) {

    // There are characters which belong to UnicodeCategory.Control but are considered as white spaces.
    // We use code point comparisons for these characters here as a temporary fix.
    
    // U+0009 = <control> HORIZONTAL TAB
    // U+000a = <control> LINE FEED
    // U+000b = <control> VERTICAL TAB
    // U+000c = <contorl> FORM FEED
    // U+000d = <control> CARRIAGE RETURN
    // U+0085 = <control> NEXT LINE
    // U+00a0 = NO-BREAK SPACE
    if ((c == ' ') || (c >= '\x0009' && c <= '\x000d') || c == '\x00a0' || c == '\x0085') {
        return (true);
    }
    return (false);
}

internal static bool IsWhiteSpace(char c) // CharUnicodeInfo.IsWhiteSpace
{
    UnicodeCategory uc = GetUnicodeCategory(c);
    // In Unicode 3.0, U+2028 is the only character which is under the category "LineSeparator".
    // And U+2029 is th eonly character which is under the category "ParagraphSeparator".
    switch (uc) {
        case (UnicodeCategory.SpaceSeparator):
        case (UnicodeCategory.LineSeparator):
        case (UnicodeCategory.ParagraphSeparator):
            return (true);
    }

    return (false);
}
```

---

Also custom characters can be removed by [`Trim(params char[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You can create it by yourself

```
var spaces = string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0, 0x10000)
                              .Select(i => ((char)i))
                              .Where(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
                              .Select(x => "'\\x" + Convert.ToInt16(x).ToString("x4") + "'"));


Console.WriteLine(spaces);
```

Answer (score 1):

"White-space characters are defined by the Unicode standard. The Trim() method removes any leading and trailing characters **that produce a return value of true when they are passed to the Char.IsWhiteSpace method**."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx

I hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find a list of the all characters Trim() will remove. But, if you are after certain characters not being removed, using

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx

which is String.Trim Method (Char[])

you can specify which characters will be removed.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Trim removes all characters that return true when calling IsWhitespace. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx(v=vs.110).aspx

Note that .net 3.5 sp1 and older behave somewhat differently: Notes to callers on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx